# QCA9565 can see APs but cannot connect to

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, network-manager, ath9k

New to this forum. Thank you!

Now I'm struggle to use my QCA9565 wifi card with my dualboot laptop. This is Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen3 (i7 5600u).

In Windows10 side,no problems occur.
But in ubuntu side,wifi is not working.

I'm very curious because netowrkmanager can see wireless acccess point in my home and try to connect and ask me password. But it cannot connect to network saying "Disconnected. Now you are offline."

And then I replaced qca9565 with intel 7265NGW with firmware installed. It worked fine.

What's wrong with ath9k? Please help me. I googled and tried various solution. But I couldn't. Now I know I can't do this by myself....

I attached systemctl output,journalctl output and wifi-script output.
And I used liveusb (updated) to claryfy what the problem is. Almost all settings and packages might be vanilla. Anybody know solution?

Thanks in advance!

[systemctl output](http://pastebin.com/rtKzut1W)
[journalctl output](http://pastebin.com/5J0vLB8b)

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 25 Aug 2016 17:34 UTC +0000

Booted last: 25 Aug 2016 00:00 UTC +0000

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed, boot=casper, quiet, splash, ---

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM [8086:15a2] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM [17aa:2227]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:4026]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8564:4000 Transcend Information, Inc. RDF8
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 067b:2773 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2773 SATAII bridge controller
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 04f2:b45d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f3:012d Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:2811 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

ath9k                 143360  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              466944  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              737280  1 ath9k
ath3k                  20480  0
cfg80211              565248  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
bluetooth             520192  30 bnep,ath3k,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
wmi                    20480  0

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp0s25' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e1100000-e1120000 

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7707 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6385 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7861781 (7.8 MB)  TX bytes:746654 (746.6 KB)

wlp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF3]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3427 (3.4 KB)  TX bytes:6392 (6.3 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      3902     1  0 17:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ath9k
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-31-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF3]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0/net/wlp4s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   ecd441e2-ff09-4e3c-a468-cc293f94a191 | aterm-8cb52f-g

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s25
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.2.6-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.2-4
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s25' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/enp0s25
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         ASIX Elec. Corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        AX88179
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ax88179_178a
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         40 (Carrier/link changed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.4/3-2.4:1.0/net/enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID             BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
aterm-fc8e9d-g   <MAC 'aterm-fc8e9d-g' [AC2]>  Infra  9     2452 MHz  54 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2  no        
aterm-fc8e9d-gw  <MAC 'aterm-fc8e9d-gw' [AC3]>  Infra  9     2452 MHz  54 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WEP        no        
001D73A97C90_G   <MAC '001D73A97C90_G' [AC1]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  --         no        
WARPSTAR-535F1E  <MAC 'WARPSTAR-535F1E' [AC6]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  no        
aterm-8cb52f-g   <MAC 'aterm-8cb52f-g' [AC4]>  Infra  10    2457 MHz  54 Mbit/s  55      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
BCW710J-72C6E-G  <MAC 'BCW710J-72C6E-G' [AN6]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
BCW710J-72C6A-G  <MAC 'BCW710J-72C6A-G' [AC5]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/aterm-8cb52f-g]] (600 root)
[connection] id=aterm-8cb52f-g | type=wifi | permissions=user:ubuntu:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF3]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=aterm-8cb52f-g
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Etc/UTC (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

enp0s25   no frequency information.

wlp4s0    13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s25   Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlp4s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC '001D73A97C90_G' [AC1]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"001D73A97C90_G"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000d3e4a5c4c4
                    Extra: Last beacon: 12ms ago
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'aterm-fc8e9d-g' [AC2]>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-13 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"aterm-fc8e9d-g"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000003421b4eae1
                    Extra: Last beacon: 12ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'aterm-fc8e9d-gw' [AC3]>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-12 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"aterm-fc8e9d-gw"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000003421b5c1f7
                    Extra: Last beacon: 12ms ago
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'aterm-8cb52f-g' [AC4]>
                    Channel:10
                    Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
                    Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"aterm-8cb52f-g"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000341c05243d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 12ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'BCW710J-72C6A-G' [AC5]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=27/70  Signal level=-83 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"BCW710J-72C6A-G"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000049192fd0c
                    Extra: Last beacon: 12652ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'WARPSTAR-535F1E' [AC6]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"WARPSTAR-535F1E"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000953ce827184
                    Extra: Last beacon: 7940ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     323EDC06388A3D0920FD7FC
depends:        mac80211,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           led_active_high:Invert LED polarity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     6FBD9F8A613FDFA282AB4FE
depends:        ath9k_hw,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     BF9F4930086BABAAF3CD9BA
depends:        ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     3FCDBF7CE71CB8FB980D59D
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     2FFAEED0245CA1D97FE1E44
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[ath3k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko
firmware:       ath3k-1.fw
license:        GPL
version:        1.0
description:    Atheros AR30xx firmware driver
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     2B85DCB887D9376A61652DD
depends:        bluetooth
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
led_active_high: -1
nohwcrypt: 0
ps_enable: 0
use_chanctx: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   18.069361] ath: phy0: WB335 2-ANT card detected
[   18.069363] ath: phy0: Set BT/WLAN RX diversity capability
[   18.078232] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining
[   18.080246] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
[   18.080250] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6a
[   18.080251] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   18.080253] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   18.080254] ath: Regpair used: 0x6a
[   18.279871] ath9k 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[   19.294493] ax88179_178a 3-2.4:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2.4, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
[   19.309738] ax88179_178a 3-2.4:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: renamed from eth0
[   19.772559] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   19.787869] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   20.094512] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   20.601602] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[   22.873028] ax88179_178a 3-2.4:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: ax88179 - Link status is: 1
[   22.879523] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: link becomes ready
[  378.478341] ax88179_178a 3-2.4:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: ax88179 - Link status is: 0
[  525.190441] wlp4s0: authenticate with <MAC 'aterm-8cb52f-g' [AC4]>
[  525.208818] wlp4s0: send auth to <MAC 'aterm-8cb52f-g' [AC4]> (try 1/3)
[  525.837817] wlp4s0: send auth to <MAC 'aterm-8cb52f-g' [AC4]> (try 2/3)
[  526.212070] wlp4s0: authenticated
[  526.245769] wlp4s0: associate with <MAC 'aterm-8cb52f-g' [AC4]> (try 1/3)
[  526.850162] wlp4s0: associate with <MAC 'aterm-8cb52f-g' [AC4]> (try 2/3)
[  527.849800] wlp4s0: associate with <MAC 'aterm-8cb52f-g' [AC4]> (try 3/3)
[  528.248125] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'aterm-8cb52f-g' [AC4]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  528.248231] wlp4s0: associated
[  528.248239] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
[  528.261451] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8188
[  528.261452] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[  528.261453] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[  528.261454] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x40
[  528.261455] ath: Country alpha2 being used: JP
[  528.261455] ath: Regpair used: 0x40
[  528.261456] ath: regdomain 0x8188 dynamically updated by country IE
[  575.068482] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'aterm-8cb52f-g' [AC4]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)

########## wireless info END ############
```